# postgis installation on linux

Tags: postgresql, arch-linux, postgis

I'm trying to install PostGIS extension on arch Linux.
here tried so far as archlinux wiki about PostGIS :

```
sudo pacman -S postgresql-libs postgis
sudo systemctl restart postgres.service
```

and go to psql -d "dbName"

so for verifying the extention exists in postgres :

```
-- verify available extensions
SELECT name, default_version,installed_version 
FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name LIKE 'postgis%' ;
```

it shows the tables . but when im trying to create extentions with these commands:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

I get this error :

> ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.5.so":
>   libproj.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

Answer (score 1):

According to the following link you could be missing the shared object if you had previously uninstalled an older version of PostGIS after having already installed the newer version:
https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/574

Other than that, there are a few bug reports of postgis issues with certain versions of postgresql, so you should confirm you aren't running affected versions. Here are the results I was looking at:

https://www.google.com/search?q=usr%2Flib%2Fpostgresql%2Fpostgis-2.5.so&oq=usr%2Flib%2Fpostgresql%2Fpostgis-2.5.so&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1247j0j4